# How can I stop Facebook from loading a preview of the URLs I post?

Tags: facebook

So I've notices from my Facebook Page Analytics that posts without link previews (thumbnail & excerpt) get over 10 times the 'reach' as posts with links previews.

I recently used an app called Buffer to post to Facebook and the first 10-15 posts included a small bit of text and a shortened link (that was clickable) - but no thumbnail or excerpt underneath.  Those posts had a reach of about 250 people.

Now, posts (from the exact same app) are generating the link preview with thumbnail and I'm reaching 10-12 people per post.

Does anybody have any insight on this?  Is there a way to disable Facebook's link detection for previewing URLs while keeping the link in the post itself?

Thanks :D

Comment: You could try not posting a link, but just include the URL in the 'message' parameter. However, your observation that links without preview get more clicks is maybe just because people are curios what's behind the link ... so you might have lots of clicks from people who close your page directly again after opening when they realize your content does not interest them - what they could have figured out before already if there was a preview. Clicks aren't everything IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't control the URL you are posting, I don't know anything you can do. But if you happen to be posting content from a personal blog, etc...you can add social meta tags, which are intended to be used to describe the content to, in this case, Facebook. The example will use Facebook's meta tags.

If you look at the tags below, this is an example from a WordPress blogs generated output for a site I did for a friend:

```
  <meta property="og:title" content="Reality Winner: Accused leaker wanted to &amp;#8216;burn the White House down&amp;#8217;"/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="This leftist loon had access to classified material! They don't do a very good job of vetting folks! Can this contractor be 'fired'?!"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.mcbanned.com/reality-winner-accused-leaker-wanted-to-burn-the-white-house-down/"/>
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="McBanned"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.mcbanned.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/6CB4A836-AFD3-4CAC-B3FF-A1D22427FE89-191-000000672C0A541C.jpeg"/>
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="660"/>
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="780"/>
```

These will tell Facebook exactly what to put in the link preview. If you have control over that, you can insert empty description, and a blank white image or something and it will just not show up. As far as completely stopping it...if you link to a simple page with only 1 image that is 200x200 or greater it will pick that one with or without the tags, but if you specify something it will choose that everytime (theoretically) so you could engineer something "blank."